# How to sum up occurrences from range?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am attempting to calculate how many same duration between two timestamps I have in a given range.

The range is `Sheet1!A1:B10`. I have two columns - first consists of starting time and second consist of ending time. So far I am able to count duration with formulae `=B1-A1` which returns `8:30`. Is there a way how to count occurrences at a given range and sum them up and print it in a cell of Sheet2?

Example sample:

```
A     | B 
01:00 | 09:00
01:30 | 12:00
02:45 | 10:45
00:00 | 08:30
04:00 | 12:00
10:00 | 18:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: add 1 more column with **`=COUNTIF(B2-A2,"="&"8:30")`**

and then you can sum this column with a formula: **`=SUM(Sheet1!C1:C10)*8.50`**

Comment: Thanks this works, but is there a way how to do it w/out adding columns?

Comment: You can hide the column!